# htaccess: convert Redirect rules to ModRewrite rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I should convert a couple of Redirect 301 rules still left in my htaccess file, as I've been told that I'd better not mix Redirect and Mod Rewrite rules in the same file.

```
Redirect 301 /bar.php http://www.foo.com/abc/bar.php 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(bar(?!bapapa\.)[^/.]+\.php)$ http://www.foo.com/abc/$1
```

1. Redirect every access to `/bar.php` to the same file in the subfolder abc
2. Redirect every access to php files beginning with `/bar` (excluding `/barbapapa.php`) to the same files in the subfolder abc

I haven't been able to convert both rules.
As for the first rule, I tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^bar.php$ "http://www.foo.com/abc/bar.php" [R=301]
```

I am correctly redirected from `/bar.php` to `/abc/bar.php`, but instead of the page I see a browser message (Firefox) stating that the server is redirecting in a way that the request can't be completed.
Any hints? thanks

edit: content of /abc/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#inherit from root htaccess and append at last
RewriteOptions inherit

#disable hotlinking but allow image bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?foo.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !images.google\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yahoo\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !bing\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !msn\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !ask\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !arianna\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yandex\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !babylon\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !virgilio\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !avg\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !delta-search.com\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !images.search.conduit.com\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search.findeer.com\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search\?q=cache [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search\/cache [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !cache [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [NC,F]

#rename old gif maps to png
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.gif$ http://www.foo.com/abc/$1.png [L,R=301]

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+abc/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(bar(?!bapapa\.)[^/.]*\.php)$ /abc/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not working here while the Redirect rules works. If I type www.foo.com/bar.php, I get a "I can't display this page"-like browser message. There aren't any other rules targeting `bar.php` in htaccess.

Comment: Made an edit since you need just one rule. Make sure above is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` and URL you try for test should be: `http://www.foo.com/bar.php` which would become `http://www.foo.com/abc/bar.php`

Comment: That's interesting, it seems that .htaccess file present in /abc folder is causing the "the server is redirecting in a way that the request cannot be completed" browser message. I tried to delete the rules one by one, but the result is always the same. Whatever is inside .htaccess file in /abc folder, the redirect from root folder doesn't work. That doesn't make any sense to me. I pasted the content of /abc/.htaccess in the main question above.

Comment: Just for testing try to rename abc/.htaccess to something else and see if that fixes this error

Comment: Yep, it works if I delete (or rename) abc/.htaccess . I'm sure I'm missing something, but if you take a look at its content in the main message, you'll see that there shouldn't be any rules conflicting with the redirect.

Comment: Ok keep abc/.htaccess just comment out `RewriteOptions inherit` line and problem will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much. As a sidenote, I'd keep R=301 rather than 302, because the redirection is not temporary. If I disable `RewriteOptions inherit` it still doesn't work (I've got absolutely no idea of the reason), but with that Rewrite Condition it works good. I'm slowly learning regular expressions, would you please explain me what it exactly does? It should be something like: if the request does not start with a letter and if it's not shorter than 3 letters (/s shorthand for whitespaces and + for including one of more instances of the preceding pattern)...

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` represents original request received by Apache from browser and it is like `/GET bar.php HTTP/1.1`. In my regex: `[A-Z]{3,}` matches GE, PUT, DELETE etc HTTP commands followed by `\s` (space) and `/+` (1 or more forward slash) followed by literal text `abc/`. `!` before `^` (line start) negates this so `RewriteRule` fires only when `THE_REQUEST` doesn't start with `/abc/`. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.